# How to write pdf object directly in PDF and get number of this object via LaTeX or expl3?

Tags: pdftex, luatex, pdf, expl3

Via Lua I can write and use an object directly in PDF:

```
local num = pdf.immediateobj("stream", "\\(a^2+b^2=c^2\\)", "/Type /SomeType /Subtype /SomeSubtype")
```

How can I do the same via `expl3` or simple LaTeX commands to make it work in pdfLaTeX and in LuaLaTeX?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the l3pdf commands. I did **not** check if the syntax of the content of the stream is correct:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{l3pdf} 
\ExplSyntaxOn
\pdf_uncompress:
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn 
\pdf_object_new:nn {mystream}{stream}
\pdf_object_write:nn {mystream}
  {{/Type /SomeType /Subtype /SomeSubtype}
  {\(a^2+b^2=c^2\)}}
\pdf_object_ref:n {mystream}
 some text ...

%to get only the number as requested in the comments
% make only sense for pdflatex and lualatex
\tl_set:Nx\l_tmpa_tl { \pdf_object_ref:n {mystream} }
\seq_set_split:NnV \l_tmpa_seq {~} { \l_tmpa_tl }
\seq_item:Nn\l_tmpa_seq{1}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

Comment: as i understood,\pdf_object_ref:n {mystream} function allow to me get number of this object?

Comment: It doesn't give the number but a reference, so e.g. `1 0 R` with pdflatex and luatex, `@pdf.obj1` for xelatex, and `{pdf.obj1}` with latex+dvips.

Comment: But i want to get only number,for example 1,but not 1 0 r,because sometimes instead of r it's possible write obj,so the best variant for me,it get only number of object such as in pdf.immediateobj function in lua.

Comment: To write the object you can use the name (mystream in my example).

Comment: yes,but i mean,that i want to get number of object,e.g 1 instead of 1 0 r. If exists any way to do this,or it works only for lua?

Comment: For some cases i must use,for example,n 0 obj,instead of n 0 r,where n - object number,so i must get n instead n 0 r,i.e only digit,which give to me number of object. How i can get only number of object without 0 r,or it possible only via lua code? Thanks.

Comment: Well it is not difficult to get the number but you should better ask a new question and show an example where it is needed so that we can consider if an additional interface is needed. (I have doubts: I never had to write n 0 obj directly myself, `\pdf_object_write` is doing this automatically.)

Comment: I haven't example yet,but probably i will have it,if i will have number of object. In my opinion it not need create new question,because in title i asked concretely about getting number of object (number not reference). You can not do example of getting number of object,i need only in command or expl3 function,which do this. Thanks.

Comment: So,as i understood,there is no way to get only number of object without lua code?

Comment: Naturally you can get the number. You could e.g. simply split `1 0 R` at the spaces and use the first part or read the internal integer which holds the number. But there is no public interface as we think that you don't need it, and we will add such an interface only if you convince us that there is a real use case.

Comment: Ok,and how i can spleat it and use the first part? For standard languages of programming i can do it,but i dont know,how i can do this using expl3 package?

Comment: I added an edit to the answer.

Comment: @AleksandrKozlovskiy The point is that objects _don't necessarily have a number_ at the TeX side: using for example `dvipdfmx`, there is _no number we can access_.